# URLs defined in a hook broken

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks, navigation

I have a content type that, on the node page, displays taxonomy term fields, which in turn link to the automatically generated taxonomy term view for that term.

I would like to overwrite the output of these links, which I have attempted to do in the code below.

The problem is that the URL comes out malformed as: `/our-work%3Ftid%3D4` rather than `/our-work?tid=4`. Note that the argument `4` is just an example.

What could be the solution here? Some thoughts:

- Am I using the right hook?
- `urlencode()` doesn't seem to work here.
- Using Drupal's `l()` function seems to output HTML, not a processed URL.
- Using Drupal's `url()` function doesn't seem to work either, I get the same output when I build the options array, etc.

  ```
  function ep3_misc_node_view_alter(&$build) {
      if ($build['#bundle'] == 'work') {
      // We cycle through this array for just integer indexes, since there are also string indices.
          for ($i = 0; isset($build['field_tags'][$i]); $i++) {
              $tid = $build['field_tags'][$i]['#options']['entity']->tid;     
              $build['field_tags'][$i]['#href'] = check_plain('our-work?tid=') . $tid;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why would not `url('our-work', array('query' => array('tid'=> $tid)))` work?

Comment: Ah, apologies - that does produce the correct URL (although my browser misleads me when I hover the link). The only issue is that the URL is absolute, how can I append the site domain to the start? I thought it was relative by default.

Comment: Do you want the URL to be absolute?

Comment: Nevermind, I just got confused. Your method is correct, I just needed to set absolute = TRUE. I will accept your answer if you wish to put it below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you should use is [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7). If you want to output an absolute URL you should use the following code:

```
function ep3_misc_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['#bundle'] == 'work') {
    for ($i = 0; isset($build['field_tags'][$i]); $i++) {
      $tid = $build['field_tags'][$i]['#options']['entity']->tid;     
      $build['field_tags'][$i]['#href'] = url('our-work', array('absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => array('tid'=> $tid)));
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want an absolute URL, replace the call to `url()` with the following one:

```
url('our-work', array('query' => array('tid'=> $tid)))
```

`check_plain()` is never used to output a URL; in fact, `url()` doesn't use it.

Comment: and don't trust what your browser shows when you hover a link. %20 and most links will be decoded for your reading ease.